# How does second level cache affect batch processing in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Say I have the following code for batch inserts.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
        final Book book = new Book("9781617291999", "Java 8 in Action", new Date());
        session.save(book);
        if(i % 50 == 0) { // 50 is the batch_size
            session.flush();
            session.clear();
        }
     }
```

The book I am referring to says that second level cache needs to be disabled for the book entity, using `session.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE)`
for the batch inserts to work.

Since `session.flush` and `session.close` mainly affect the first level cache, How does enabling/disabling second level cache affect the process of Batch Inserts here?

Comment: What hibernate version is used in the book? I found a reference to this in 3.3 docs, but not in 5.4 docs.

Comment: Isn't the point in the book simply that, while `session.flush()` and `session.close()` do affect 1st level cache exclusively, `session.save()` affects both?